# Will creating a new Task in a classes destructor run properly? C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

So I have a class that is set out like this:

```
public class NetworkServer
{
    private BlockingCollection<byte[]> receivingQueue;

    public NetworkServer(IPEndPoint endpoint, int packetsize)
    {
        receivingQueue = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>(new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>());
        // Do some other stuff here
    }

    public ~NetworkServer()
    {
        // Do some stuff here
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach<byte[]>(receivingQueue, item => SomeOtherClass.ParseItem(item)));
    }
}
```

With the `Task.Factory.StartNew` in the destructor, I was wondering if that would create a new thread that will continue running even though the instance of `NetworkServer` might be garbage collected. If this wouldn't work what would be the best way to parse each of those items on a new thread/parse the items after the instance of `NetworkServer` has been GC'd. Also, `ParseItem` will be in a different class in-case that wasn't clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing that? This really is asking for trouble...

Comment: @carlosfigueira I thought that was a destructor. I realize whats wrong now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it will.

But, that's not a destructor. That's finalizer.

If you've got a machine with 16GB of RAM, the first finalizer may be run hours after the start. That's definitely a bad design.

Comment: Oh, now I realize whats happening. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

That's truly awful! Don't do it! You don't know much at all about the context from which the finalizer will run. Look to fix your design if you think you need to do this kind of thing - it has a code stench.